# Matching strings even if they start with white spaces in SED

Tags: sed, spaces, substitution

I'm having issues matching strings even if they start with any number of white spaces. It's been very little time since I started using regular expressions, so I need some help

Here is an example. I have a file (file.txt) that contains two lines

```
#String1='Test One'
String1='Test Two'
```

Im trying to change the value for the second line, without affecting line 1 so I used this

```
sed -i "s|String1=.*$|String1='Test Three'|g"
```

This changes the values for both lines. How can I make sed change only the value of the second string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gnu sed, you match spaces using `\s`, while other sed implementations usually work with the `[[:space:]]` character class.  So, pick one of these:

```
sed 's/^\s*AWord/AnotherWord/'
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*AWord/AnotherWord/'
```

Since you're using `-i`, I assume GNU sed.  Either way, you probably shouldn't retype your word, as that introduces the chance of a typo.  I'd go with:

```
sed -i "s/^\(\s*String1=\).*/\1'New Value'/" file
```

Move the `\s*` outside of the parens if you don't want to preserve the leading whitespace.

Comment: Shouldn't I use the g flag in sed for this?

Comment: The `g` flag indicates that you want to match all of the instances of the pattern in a single line.  Your pattern matches the whole line, so there can only be zero or one instances of your pattern on the line.  Thus, the `g` flag is irrelevant in this case.  You're thinking that you want to match multiple lines, which sed does already unless you limit it by specifying a line selector / range selector or similar.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, try:

```
sed -i "s|^\s*String1=.*$|String1='Test Three'|" file
```

or

```
sed -i "/^\s*String1=/s/=.*/='Test Three'/" file
```

Comment: The second option will not work as expected if the RHS includes an `=` character.  However, the first is the one >90% of people who use sed would go with, so that's probably the answer he's looking for.

Comment: Thanks @dannysauer! I improved the second option so that the RHS may contain `=` characters..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions you could use to go about your problem

If you want to ignore lines that begin with a comment character such as '#' you could use something like this:

```
sed -i "/^\s*#/! s|String1=.*$|String1='Test Three'|g" file.txt
```

which will only operate on lines that do not match the regular expression `/.../!` that begins `^` with optional whiltespace`\s*` followed by an octothorp `#`

The other option is to include the characters before 'String' as part of the substitution.  Doing it this way means you'll need to capture `\(...\)` the group to include it in the output with `\1`

```
sed -i "s|^\(\s*\)String1=.*$|\1String1='Test Four'|g" file.txt
```

Comment: The questions says not to change the value of the commented string, while the second option here will change both values (albeit while keeping the comment char intact).  In both cases, since you're matching the whole line, there's not much point in including the `\g` modifier at the end; there's only one instance of the whole line on the line. ;)

Comment: Both options I provided have been tested with the OP's example, and neither replaces text in the commented out line.  This is because both are anchored to that start of the line.  I left the `|g` modifier in there because the OP had it and I assumed he had a reason for it being there.

Comment: I must have been looking at a different answer or something, because you're right; the second answer is fine.  Nevermind, then. :)

Answer (score -1):

Using `awk` you could do:

```
awk '/String1/ && f++ {$2="Test Three"}1' FS=\' OFS=\' file
#String1='Test One'
String1='Test Three'
```

It will ignore first hits of `string1` since `f` is not true.

Comment: If someone gives one minus, it would be nice to know why, so I can learn from it.

Comment: Probably because the question is tagged as `sed` and not `awk`.  Giving solutions using other languages/technologies than asked for can often garner downvotes.  I'm not saying it's right, I'm just sayin'

Comment: There's also the observation that this answer literally replaces the second (and any subsequent) instances of String1, rather than skipping commented versions.  And it doesn't require that String1 be on the LHS or be just String1 - so it will match things like "String10='pie'" and "cows='NotString1'".  I'd be inclined to use `=` as the record separator and match $1 against /^[[:space:]]*String1$/, personally.